# Querying for BIGINTEGER data type in Android SQlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a scenario where I need to query for BIGINTEGER data type column value from a table of SQLIte  DB in my android app.
for retrieving string data type we will retrieve like below :
mycursor.getString(0);

Can anyone help me how can we query for Biginteger data type.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Retrieve it as a String, and instantiate the `BigInteger` with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The widest integer type `Cursor`s handle is `long`, but SQLite utilizes dynamic typing, so you can retrieve the value as a `String` and instantiate the `BigInteger` with that. For example:

```
Cursor cursor;
...
String value = cursor.getString(...);
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(value);
```